# Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers while committing state from actions in quasar

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuex, quasar

My app is working normally. When I navigate to `/login` page, and hit `login` button then the login `action` is called, which is shown below in the code, user information is then stored in the store. But the problem is while accessing protected route, I've called `beforeEnter` function in the routes.js file where the user is redirected based on the authentication. So if I try to access `/dashboard`, initially the user is not authenticated. So, it redirects the user to the login page. Now after being redirected to the login page, if I enter all the credentials and press login button, again it calls `login` action as previously mentioned, but this time wherever it finds `commit` function to mutate the state, it says `Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.`. This error message is shown in the console only if I `redirect` to the login page from `beforeEnter` using `next('/login')` function and hit login button else the app is working perfectly.

`user.js (user module in store)`

```
const state = {
    token: null,
    user:{
        username: null
    }
}

const getters = {
  authenticated(state){
    return state.token && state.user.username && true
  }
}

const mutations = {
  login(state, payload){
    state.user.username = payload.username
    state.token = payload.token
  }
}

const actions = {
  login({commit}, payload){
    commit('login', {...payload, token: "ja;lfjalf"})
  }    
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions,
  state
}
```

```
routes.js
```

```
import store from 'src/store'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/Home.vue') },
      { path: '/login', component: () => import('pages/Login.vue') },
      { 
        path: '/dashboard', 
        component: () => import('pages/Dashboard.vue'), 
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
          // prints true if authenticated
          console.log(store().getters['user/authenticated'])
          if(store().getters['user/authenticated']){
            return next()
          }
          next('login')
        }
      },
    ]
  },

  {
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)*',
    component: () => import('pages/Error404.vue')
  }
]

export default routes
```

```
login.vue
```

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="login">
        <input v-model="username" placeholder="Username" type="text"/>
        <input v-model="password" placeholder="Password" type="text"/>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    import {mapActions} from 'vuex'
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                username: "thomas",
                password: "thomas"
            }
        },
        methods:{
            ...mapActions({
                signin: 'user/login'
            }),
            login(){
               this.signin({
                   username: this.username,
                   password: this.password
               }) 
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

```
src/
   store/
        index.js
```

```
import { store } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import user from './user'

export default store(function (/* { ssrContext } */) {
  const Store = createStore({
    modules: {
      user
    },

    strict: process.env.DEBUGGING
  })

  return Store
})
```

`Note: I updated post with minimun code`

Comment: Please, provide all relevant code, i.e. login page and store getters

Comment: You should not invoke your `store` in `beforeEnter` hook, just access `getters` property like you would do on a normal object: `store.getters['user/authenticated']`

Comment: @EstusFlask have a look i've updated the post.

Comment: @transGLUKator have a look once, i've updated what store looks like, it is returning function so I have to call store() and access .getters else it says getters is undefined.

Comment: There seem to be no problems so far. It's not shown where `login` is dispatched. It's unclear why `store` is a function. It's not supposed to be. It's not shown too. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. If you're unsure if it can, consider isolating the problem first.

Comment: @Estus Flask I initialized the project using ```quasar create projectname``` command. It was like that.

Comment: https://github.com/thapaliyaprasanga/reproducequasarauth . Check this link, i've reproduced the error with minimun code.